# TileMill with non map images

Tags: image, html, custom-action, tile

I'm building a web app that will use the tiling, zooming, marker and other functionality associated with map applications, however i dont need to use all this Geolocation and other stuff that TileMill requires as my application will be loading medical images not maps. Is it possible to import a custom image into TileMill? If so how? Maybe TileMill is completely unsuited to my specific application, if so could someone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at one of these?

- PanoJS http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/
- jQuery TileZoom http://labs.webcodingstudio.com/tilegenerator/

Both libraries include scripts to generate all the tiles from the original photos and JavaScript libraries to display these on a web page.

Answer (score 2):

It is doable but Tilemill is probably an overkill what you're looking for.
Simple plugins like the ones mentioned by @thisguyzaphod could do the trick. If you're looking to use featureful state of the art tile zooming, I would go with Leaflet.js it can be specifically used for non-geographic content like this page documents:

http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/

You can probably find some other valuable pointers here:
[Is Leaflet a good tool for non-map images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110763/is-leaflet-a-good-tool-for-non-map-images)

Good luck!