# Possible to use my own (LARGE) map with Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

I've been using Leaflet for a while, and recently came into possession a large (and I mean large) PNG image containing a satellite photo of a specific area (a couple km in radius). I'd love to be able to switch to that to compare it with the current map in Leaflet.js. How would I accomplish this?

I can easily find out which pixel position corresponds to a certain real-life GPS coordinate, and from that Leaflet.js should in theory be able to lay my large map image in the map, right? But how? That's the question.

```
        var bookmarks = L.layerGroup();

        var layer1 = L.tileLayer('<URL_GOING_TO_STREET_MAP>', { id: 'mapbox.one' }); // maxZoom: 18, 
        var layer2 = L.tileLayer('<URL_GOING_TO_SATELLITE_MAP>', { id: 'mapbox.two' });
        var layer3 = L.tileLayer('<URL_GOING_TO_STREET_AND_SATELLITE_COMBO_MAP>', { id: 'mapbox.three' });

        var theMap = L.map('map', {
            center: [ <CENSORED>, <CENSORED> ],
            zoom: 4,
            layers: [ layer3, bookmarks ]
        });

        var baseLayers = {
            "Standard": layer1,
            "Satellite": layer2,
            "Satellite + info combo": layer3
        };

        var overlays = {
            "Bookmarks": bookmarks
        };

        L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(theMap);

        fetch('./data/generated.geojson').then(function(response) { return response.json() }).then(function(actualData)
        {
            L.geoJSON(actualData).bindTooltip(function (layer)
            {
                return layer.feature.properties.name;
            }).openTooltip().addTo(bookmarks);
        });
```

Comment: Get the lat-long coordinates for the corners of the image, create a `L.ImageOverlay` from that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Leaflet a good tool for non-map images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110763/is-leaflet-a-good-tool-for-non-map-images)

Comment: Not duplicate. The linked-to question didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining the actual coordinates of your raster image (satellite photo), so that you can later on overlay it on common Tiles, is called *georeferencing*.

You have plenty online resources describing possible procedures, e.g. https://www.mapbox.com/help/georeferencing-imagery/.

You also have online tools that might suit your need: https://www.georeferencer.com/

The idea is to determine the coordinates of the corners of your raster image.

Once you have those coordinates, you can use Ivan's [Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated) plugin to position (and possibly rotate and skew) your image:

> Display rotated and skewed images in your LeafletJS maps.
>
> This LeafletJS plugin adds a new class, `L.ImageOverlay.Rotated`, subclass of `L.ImageOverlay`. The main difference is that the position of `L.ImageOverlay` is defined by a `L.LatLngBounds` (the `L.LatLngs` of the top-left and bottom-right corners of the image), whereas `L.ImageOverlay.Rotated` is defined by **three** points (the `L.LatLngs` of the top-left, top-right and bottom-left corners of the image).
>
> The image will be rotated and skewed (as the three corner points might not form a 90-degree angle).

[Code sample](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated/blob/gh-pages/demo.html#L43-L60) taken from the plugin [demo page](http://ivansanchez.github.io/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated/demo.html):

```js
var point1 = L.latLng(40.52256691873593, -3.7743186950683594),
    point2 = L.latLng(40.5210255066156, -3.7734764814376835),
    point3 = L.latLng(40.52180437272552, -3.7768453359603886);

L.imageOverlay.rotated("URL-to-image", point1, point2, point3, {
  attribution: "&copy; <a href='url'>SOURCE</a>"
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Well, I can find out the GPS coordinates of the corners of my image, so I don't have to upload the (very massive, copyright-protected, must-be-kept-private-anyway) image file to that service. However, the problem is actually figuring out how to implement this in Leaflet.

Comment: I didn't mean to post that last comment. I pressed Enter to get a new line, but instead it published the comment. Anyway, I'm now going to add the actual source code I have to the question if you wish to help me, as I can tell I'm never going to figure this out on my own...

Comment: Simply adapt the code sample from the plugin demo page. Reproduced here in the above updated answer for simplicity.

Comment: I don't understand what those points mean. But either way, I get this error: TypeError: L.imageOverlay.rotated is not a function

Comment: As said in the plugin description: "three points (the L.LatLngs of the top-left, top-right and bottom-left **corners** of the image)". Regarding the error you report, it sounds like you have not included the plugin script before trying to use it. Please open a different question should you need help in using it.

Comment: Ah. It's a plug-in. Well, I eventually figured it out thanks to your help. Very cool.

Comment: (Also, I would upvote you if only this silly site would let me.)